# Filezilla: TLS connection established then timeout after 20 seconds

Tags: filezilla, tls

I had to rebuild Windows, and lost my Filezilla Site Manager entries.

After recreating my site entry, and attempting to connection, I see:

```
Status: Resolving address of cp95.ezyreg.com
Status: Connecting to 27.121.64.95:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (27,121,64,95,195,19).
Command:    MLSD
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

`ezyreg.com's` support say I should use insecure plain FTP, but I refuse, knowing it is a security hazard.

Their alternative is to use cpanel's File Manager, which is not an efficient solution.

I don't recall connecting on plain FTP to this host before the computer rebuild.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try removing the `passive` option?

Comment: No, but when I try that @JuliePelletier, the symptom doesn't change. Thanks.

Comment: To try: (1) Set the FileZilla Transfer Mode to Active, (2) Try again with firewall disabled, (3) If you control the FTP server see [this article](http://www.alvincheong.com/2010/08/ftp-server-hangs-at-mlsd-command-when-accessing-with-filezilla/), (4) Test the server with the [Online FTP tester](https://ftptest.net/) and report on the result.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc. 1) Active does not resolve it. 2) FileZilla connects to other sites fine with Firewall on. 3) I don't control the server. 4) I'd prefer not to use the FTP Tester (I receive `Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:21...Status: Connection established`...)

Comment: Please at least use the Online FTP tester to report on the response to the FEAT command - it might be that FileZilla does not recognize correctly if the server is compatible with the MLSD command of FTP. Try another FTP client with this site. This ["answer"](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=11405&start=15) by FileZilla about this same problem is really discouraging (see last entry).

Comment: Hi @harrymc. I'm happy to use WinSCP, which works for this host. I'm paranoid about using the Online FTP tester.

Comment: WinSCP does not use the MLSD command - it uses instead the older LIST command. MLSD was added via RFC 3659 in 2007 and ezyreg maybe uses an older FTP server. Therefore I conclude, based also on the link I gave above, that FileZilla uses a command that is unsafe with older FTP servers. All you can do is complain to ezyreg Support and use WinSCP. I will add later an answer to that effect. BTW, I like Core FTP LE better than WinSCP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the list of the known facts :

- FileZilla to ezyreg.com times-out on the FTP command MLSD after 20 seconds
- Increasing the timeout to 120 seconds does not help
- FileZilla works with other sites
- I can see in the FileZilla log above that it does not issue the FTP command
  FEAT to verify that the server fully supports MLSD
- WinSCP works correctly with ezyreg.com
- WinSCP uses the FTP command LIST instead of MLSD
- MLSD was introduced in [RFC 3659 - Extensions to FTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659) in 2007

My conclusions are :

1. The FTP server of ezyreg.com does not handle correctly the MLSD command.
2. FileZilla uses MLSD without verifying that it is supported

We can add to this the answer by a FileZilla admin from 2009 to the post
[Empty file listing with Filezilla 3.2.4 - MLSD problem ?](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=11405&start=15) :

> I'm usually a very calm person, but I'm short of smashing things due
> to your irrational reluctance to fix broken servers and firewalls.
> Closing this topic before I go insane.

So there it is : FileZilla does not support "broken" servers such as ezyreg.com.

What you can do :

1. Complain to ezyreg.com Support that 2016 is long enough for them to get
   a modern FTP server that supports correctly the 2007 FTP extensions.
   (EDIT: Apparently the FTP server is recent enough, so in that case it might be
   badly installed or bad parameters.)
2. Use another FTP client for ezyreg.com

If you are considering using WinSCP, I remark that [Core FTP LE](http://www.coreftp.com/) is also
a very good FTP client.

Comment: Connecting with `openssl` that server identifies as `220 ProFTPD 1.3.5 Server (ProFTPD Default Installation) [::ffff:27.121.64.95]` and `FEAT` response includes `MLST modify*;perm*;size*;type*;unique*;UNIX.group*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.owner*;` . (And FWIW it uses fairly new *crypto*: TLSv1.2 ECDHE GCM.) The forum you link to says FileZilla *does* check FEAT but gets fooled because a firewall in between lets through FEAT but screws up actual MLSD; if applicable here that might be ezreg's fault but might not.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: It's someone's fault, somewhere between FileZilla and ezyreg.com. What's clear is that both do not work together - the rest above is just theory, perhaps supported by the arrogant attitude of FileZilla developers. If the server is pretty recent, then it might be badly installed.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Settings" and choose "Connection" (should be the first), then change timeout from 20 to whatever you want or 0 to disable.

Comment: Thanks Mikael. I increased the timeout to 120 seconds and the connection still times out.

Comment: Symptom occurs on active and passive connection types.

Comment: Does it still happen after 20 seconds?

Comment: Yes @MikaelKjær.